# How to use if/else inside ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a database of "Albums". I've used ListView to show them to client. albums have a "price" property. i want to show the price itself if it's not 0 and show "Free" if it is 0.
I've tried the code in aspx page inside ListView:

```
<%#:
if (Item.price == 0) { String.Format(" Free"); }
else {String.Format("{0:c}", Item.price);}
%>
```

but i get an error:

```
Invalid expression term 'if'
```

how to fix it? (please note i'm new to ASP.NET, and actually I've copied most of the code to create this project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ternary operator:

```
<%# (Item.price == 0) ? "Free" : String.Format("{0:c}", Item.price) %>
```

Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure where you added that code but it looks like you copied the code to the .aspx ...
try to add an suitable event to your list view instead and add that logic in your code behind into the event handler.